# AngularJS: Instance resource with POST errors out on promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I am attempting to build a generic filter which needs to be able to handle - based on configuration - parameters. Both a resource instance and a service.

I have the following factory code:

```
angular.module('sample').factory('Sample', function($resource) {
  var methods = {
    search: {
      method: 'POST',
      isArray: true
    }
  }
  var Sample = new $resource('/sample', methods);

  Sample.prototype.elasticFilter = function (search) {
    var query = {
      query: {
        filtered: {
          query: {
            wildcard: {
              name: '*' + search.toLowerCase() + '*'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return this.$search(query);
  }
  return Sample;
});
```

Now if I do the following in my directive:

```
scope.search = function (search) {
  Sample.elasticFilter(search).$promise.then(function () {
    handle
  });
```

this results in

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

printing out `Sample.elasticFilter(search)`, the result is directly a `Promise`.

Modifying the directive to read directily off `Sample.elasticFilter(search).then` results in:

`TypeError: value.push is not a function`.

For non-instance-resources (e.g. NOT newed up, rather service directly), `.$promise` works fine.

Why is this happening? How can I work around it? When does a resource have a $promise, and when does it not?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a "feature" https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11767

The only way to really work around this is to not use isArray on instance level resource methods.